# Auto Input for User Install a Separate Package on Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm automating a Python script to install certbot for the end-user. [This is the tutorial I'm using for manual installation.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-debian-10) Currently I have:

```
host = example.com
os.system("sudo apt-get install python3-acme python3-certbot python3-mock python3-openssl python3-pkg-resources "
          "python3-pyparsing python3-zope.interface && sudo apt-get install python3-certbot-nginx && sudo systemctl"
          "reload nginx && sudo ufw allow 'Nginx Full' &7 sudo ufw delete allow 'Nginx HTTP' sudo certbot --"
          "nginx -d " + host)
```

From here, a prompt comes up asking the following:

```
Select the appropriate number [1-2] then [enter] (press 'c' to cancel):
```

I want to be able to enter it using this instead:

```
import subprocess
a = subprocess.run(["nginx", "-d " + host])
a.communicate('2')
```

Because the certbot prompt doesn't come immediately and there are further printed text after the prompt appears. Suggestions?

Comment: Maybe [`pexpect`](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) helps?

Comment: Is there a way to do it without it? I did it successfully with spawn, expect, and sendline (thanks!), but I'd rather do it without pexpect. Know how?